# Proper tags for objects in jsdoc

Tags: javascript, documentation, tags

What is the proper way to document objects of this style in jsdoc:

```
/**

*/

var strings = 
{
    /**

    */  
    stripHTML: function(html)
    {
        //does something
    },
    /**

    */
    validHTML: function(html)
    {
        //does something else
    }
}
```

Namely the proper parameter to define the object, and to recognize the sub-functions as part of 'strings'. I know about @param, @return etc, I just don't know the main definition for this type of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use @namespace for "strings"

the methods would simply use @function (though it's obvious to jsdoc what they are

**Edit**
In your particular example you may want to use something like:

```
/**
    describe purpose
*/
String.prototype.stripHTML = function()
{
    //does something with this
}

/**
    describe purpose
*/
String.prototype.validHTML = function()
{
    //does something else with this
}
```

then used like this:

```
var str = "bob<br/>";
str = str.stripHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I know about the prototypes, but thanks for the tip. The script I used as a demo has somewhat misleading names.

Comment: ahhh, ok. well, for singletons that function as a namespace, just use the @namespace. It does get to be a pain when you have complex structures, though

Comment: Is there any way of marking the function, say 'validHTML', so that it appears to be a method of or linked to 'strings'? Looking at the generated documentation there's no way to really tell that it's a member of such.

Comment: the jsdoc documentation generators don't really have an understanding of the built-in objects, just the grammar. you can use @memberOf to explicitly define the relationship though

Comment: are you familiar with the jsdoc-toolkit wiki at http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/w/list

Comment: I am, but am still having problems with it. When I use memberOf it throws the error '>> WARNING: Trying to document saveContent as a member of undocumented symbol saveState\.' I feel like I've tried all possible tags but can't get the two to link up.

Comment: For the above ^^ :/** @namespace */ var saveState = { /** @memberOf saveState */ saveContent:function() {} }

Comment: in that case, @memberOf would not be appropriate as saveState isn't an instantiation of a class. you want /** @static */ saveContent:function().... see http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagStatic

Comment: I'm going to have to sincerely apologize for the last few comments... It turns out I was not saving over the original due to a small typo in the file name. The jsdoc was in-fact catching them properly as static. 
Thanks for your patience!

Comment: hehe, no worries. Glad it's all sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are good arguments for defining object member functions by setting prototype, sometimes that is not practical. I thought I would post an answer that does not re-factor the code. It uses the same idea as @Jonathan's answer.

```
/**
 * @namespace
 * Custom String functions
 */
var strings = 
{
    /**
     * Strips the HTML away
     */  
    stripHTML: function(html)
    {
        //does something
    },

    /**
     * Ensures the HTML is valid
     */
    validHTML: function(html)
    {
        //does something else
    }
}
```

The example from: [JSDoc-Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagNamespace) was exactly what I was after.